# Error on the TIBCO activity HTTP starter

Tags: tomcat, tibco

TIBCO embedes the tomcat to handle the HTTP requests in the HTTP starter activity. This error happened while executing the send HTTP response activity with close connection option.

---

Tomcat version 5.5.7

```
 Error [BW-Core] BWENGINE-100001 null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:751)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:183)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.finish(Response.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:104)
    at com.tibco.plugin.share.http.wssdk.ServletTransportDriver.sendMessage(ServletTransportDriver.java:327)
    at com.tibco.plugin.share.http.wssdk.ServletTransportDriver.sendMessage(ServletTransportDriver.java:260)
    at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.bwhttp.impl.DefaultBwHttpReplyHandler.fault(DefaultBwHttpReplyHandler.java:94)
    at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.bwhttp.impl.HttpEventContext.failed(HttpEventContext.java:124)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.removeJob(JobPool.java:1400)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.runx(JobDispatcher.java:252)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.run(JobDispatcher.java:200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve tried a workaround which is splitting writing the response into two parts :

1. HTTP response activity for flushing the response to the client to make sure that the client have received the response data.
2. HTTP response activity for closing the connection.

I hope this could help!